# Printing values from a deeply nested object as an array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I have the following object and I am trying to create a function that prints the result as an array that contains only the nested 'rgba' values as an array:

```
const colorObject = {
  "colors": [
    {
      "color": "black",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
      "rgba": [255, 255, 255, 1]
    }
    },
    {
      "color": "white",
      "category": "value",
      "code": {
      "rgba": [0, 0, 0, 1]
    }
    },
    {
      "color": "red",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
      "rgba": [255, 0, 0, 1]
    }
    },
    {
      "color": "blue",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
      "rgba": [0, 0, 255, 1]
    }
    },
    {
      "color": "yellow",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
      "rgba": [255, 255, 0, 1]
    }
    },
      {
        "color": "green",
        "category": "hue",
        "type": "secondary",
        "code": {
        "rgba": [0, 255, 0, 1]
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

So far, I have gone the long route and produced the result, but I know that there must be a more efficient way:

```
function dispArrayRgbaCode() {
  let arrayRgbaCode = [
    colorObject['colors'][0]['code']['rgba'], 
    colorObject['colors'][1]['code']['rgba'], 
    colorObject['colors'][2]['code']['rgba'], 
    colorObject['colors'][3]['code']['rgba'], 
    colorObject['colors'][4]['code']['rgba'], 
    colorObject['colors'][5]['code']['rgba'], 
  ]
  console.log(arrayRgbaCode)
}

dispArrayRgbaCode()
```

I am brand new and have checked out working with objects in the MDN docs.  I figured that asking the community would behoove me so I can learn from peers as well.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Mapper and achieve this as below..

```js
const colorObject = {
  "colors": [{
      "color": "black",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255, 255, 255, 1]
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "white",
      "category": "value",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0, 0, 0, 1]
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "red",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255, 0, 0, 1]
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "blue",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0, 0, 255, 1]
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "yellow",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255, 255, 0, 1]
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "green",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "secondary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0, 255, 0, 1]
      }
    },
  ]
};


var newRgbaArray = colorObject.colors.map(function(rgbaItem) {
  return rgbaItem.code.rgba;
});

console.log(newRgbaArray);
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.  I see that there are many ways to apply the map feature.  I will explore the nested data and see how else I can apply this technique in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the `rgba` values from each object in the `colorObject.colors` array and return an array of them:

```
colorObject.colors.map(c => c.code.rgba)
```

Demo:

```js
const colorObject = {
  "colors": [{
      "color": "black",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255, 255, 255, 1]
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "white",
      "category": "value",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0, 0, 0, 1]
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "red",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255, 0, 0, 1]
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "blue",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0, 0, 255, 1]
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "yellow",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255, 255, 0, 1]
      }
    },
    {
      "color": "green",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "secondary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [0, 255, 0, 1]
      }
    },
  ]
}

console.log(colorObject.colors.map(c => c.code.rgba));
```

Comment: wow, it amazes me how many functions are built it to turn a page of code into a line.  I am going to play around with the map feature.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: @Tepe3 indeed - the downside is that some of them can make your code almost unreadable! :-) but this particular case is clear and easy to see what is going on.